# 'gomobile.user u' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I'm trying to query all the data of my `user` table in the schema `gomobile` of my DerbyDB.

I've successfully established a connection to my database and created a JPA Entity, with all its columns corresponding to the database table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "gomobile")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // all columns

    public static List<User> getAll() {
        String queryString = "SELECT u FROM gomobile.user u";
        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Eclipselink").createEntityManager();
        return em.createQuery(queryString, User.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

This is the stracktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM gomobile.user as u]. 
[14, 41] 'gomobile.user as u' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1625)
    at com.sap.sapchat.jpa.entities.User.getAll(User.java:45)
    at com.sap.sapchat.jpa.entities.InitDatabase.main(InitDatabase.java:50)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM gomobile.user as u]. 
[14, 41] 'gomobile.user as u' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
    ... 3 more
```

My persistence declaration in the persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="Eclipselink" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>jpa.entities.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/gomobile;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="gomobile" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**EDIT**

If I use:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM gomobile.user u";
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT * FROM gomobile.user u]. 
[38, 38] A select statement must have a FROM clause.
[7, 7] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
[9, 38] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1625)
    at com.sap.sapchat.jpa.entities.User.getAll(User.java:75)
    at com.sap.sapchat.jpa.entities.InitDatabase.main(InitDatabase.java:64)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT * FROM gomobile.user u]. 
[38, 38] A select statement must have a FROM clause.
[7, 7] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
[9, 38] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Have you tried running just that 1 SELECT statement interactively against your Derby database? Also, what is the FULL Derby exception: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: @BryanPendleton I don't get a `SQL exception`. I get an `IllegalArgumentException`. If I try running the query above via JDBC, I get an error. I've to use `SELECT * FROM gomobile.user`. I'll update my thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no entity called gomobile.user, so you cannot use it in your JPQL queries.  JPQL is object based, and does not use the tables/schema and fields directly like you would in SQL.

You should be using just "SELECT u FROM User u", as the Entity you are quering is named "User" by default.

Comment: Well then I get `Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM User u]. 
[14, 27] The abstract schema type 'User' is unknown.`.

Comment: This usually means the name in the query doesn't match the name defined for the entity.  If you set logging to Finest, it should show what gets set when it loads the persistence unit.  Does the persistence unit work for inserts or anything else?

Comment: Be careful, it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because JPA expects JPQL syntax and native SQL like yours is not allowed directly. However there is a way that entity manager supports which is a easy alternative where normal SQL can be used directly.

Link for example on how to use native SQL in JPA :  http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/